# Server side events not firing the first time when asp validator fires

Tags: asp.net, validation, server-side

Our application has a group of settings that include a checkbox, textbox and asp validator.  To change one of the settings, you must first enable the textbox using the checkbox.  If the validation fails then a message appears, via the validator, telling the user what values are valid.  Once this happens and I attempt to uncheck the checkbox (this action should disable the textbox again and restore the previous value of the textbox) nothing happens and the textbox remains that same.  I must check and uncheck the checkbox again before the CheckedChanged event is finally fired.

It may be important to note that these are in UpdatePanels and that at one point these did work within the panels.  We are at a loss and would appreciate some ideas if anyone has any.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. In my case it had to do with an updatepanel.
I had an updatepanel with a couple of checkboxes. Based on the setting of one of these checkboxes  validators had to be enabled/disabled but the validators were located in another control outside the updatepanel.

What happens is that if you check/uncheck a checkbox an ajax-postback is fired. Because of this the clientside validation is not correctly restored. So when you submit the page, the clientside validation is not found and instead the server-side validation fires. Because your page did a complete postback, the client side validation is bound again. When you click the submit button again you find they will work.

The simplest solution is to put the controls with clientside validators in the update panel to.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the code, at least the aspx, would help to spot the problem.

Without any code, my best guess would be to set your CheckBox `CausesValidation` property to `"false"` it will allow it to post-back even if there is a validation error.